# Python: Update a variable inside the print function

Tags: python

```
a=1
print(a=2)
```

I am new in python. I tried to change the value for the variable `a` inside the `print` function. However, it's showing a syntax error. This concept will work in other languages. Could you please explain why it's showing a syntax error?

Comment: `print` is for *pritning* you can not expect it to do something else you can simply do that on line like you did `a=1`.

Comment: What would the behaviour be? Why would you want to use it? Also, that syntax in Python is used for something different, as any tutorial should teach you...

Comment: I want to know why its syntax error is coming

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt in python we can do print(a+1). I just know the reason why its assignment is not working.

Comment: A tutorial would have told you why, because that syntax is used elsewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` is in-built function which takes `positional` and some `keyword args`.
Here you are calling `print` function with `keyword args a`  with value `2`, but  there is no `keyword args` named `a` in `print function`.

You can't update the value inside a `function` call

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the closest you can get:

```
a = 1
print('{} {}'.format(exec('a=2'), a))
```

**Edit**: I thought wrong. @Sayandip Dutta fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using python< v3.8, in my opinion, the closest you can get (pun intended) is:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> print(dict().get(exec('a=2'),a))
2
>>> a
2
```

Or,

```
>>> print({exec('a=2'):a}[None])
2
>>> a
2
```

Or,

```
>>> exec('a=2;print(a)')
2
```

Comment: But in practice please just set `a` before the call to `print`

Answer (score 0):

Actually,what you would encounter is a TypeError,

```
>>> a=1
>>> print(a=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#44>", line 1, in <module>
    print(a=2)
TypeError: 'a' is an invalid keyword argument for print()
```

From the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), you can find that if there was an `=` sign, the `print()` function would take it as an keyword argument unless it is given as a string.

So what actually happened here is that python tries to identify `a` as an argument, which obviously is not defined in the `print()` function. Therefore, it finds it as an invalid argument.

If you need to update the value of `a`, it is advisable to do it before the `print()` function and then print it.